# foreach or array_map to find in multidemeantional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidemeantional array like the following: (Sorry it is large array and I want to show the structure)

```
  [project2020] => Array
        (
            [title] => title2020
            ..
            [terms] =>
            [releases] => Array
                (
                    [1.1.4] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name2020 1.1.4
                            [version] => 1.1.4
                            ..
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [Release type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => type two
                                            [1] => type three
                                        )
                                )
                            [grade] => A
                        )
                    [1.0.0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name2019 1.0.0
                            [version] => 1.0.0
                            ..
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [Release type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => type one
                                            [1] => type three
                                        )
                                )
                            [grade] => D
                        )
                   .....
                )
         )
[project2019] => Array
        (
 ..........
```

I am getting confuse to how find the necessary information that I need and I do not know if I can use array_map or not. I need to store and find if my project has a Release type of one. Consider we have more than 20 different versions like "1.0.0 and 1.1.4" for each project and I have more than 10 projects.

The output should be like the following:

I need to walk by this order [project2020] check each versions [1.0.0][terms] and in the [Release type] check for "type one" if "type one" exist then I can return the [project2020].

Here is the code that I wrote which it dow not work :(

```
  foreach ($myOriginalArray as $key => $projects) {
        $update[] = ['project' => $key];
        foreach ($projects as $secondKey => $versions) {
          foreach ($versions as $thirdKey => $releaseType) {
            $releaseType[] = $releaseType['terms']['Release type'];
            foreach ($releaseType as $fourthKey => $type) {
            if ($type !== "type one") {
               continue;
            }

          }
        }
   }
return $update;
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$updates = [];
foreach ($myOriginalArray as $key => $project) {
    foreach ($project['releases'] as $release) {
        if (in_array('type one', $release['terms']['Release type'] ?? [])) {
            $updates[] = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return $updates;
```

This will check for `type one` accross all versions of each project and return the projects that do have any release with the type being set.